# Computing coordinates of point knowing coordinates of observer point, azimuth and distance to unknown point?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have the longitude and latitude of a known point O(x,y) where x and y are obtained from transforming the longitude and latitude from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 32635. This is the observer point. I have another point A(x1, y1) whose coordinates I don't know, but I know the distance from O to A in meters and the azimuth from O to A in radians.

How can I compute the coordinates of A knowing only these?

A function in Qgis in C++ would be the most useful, or at least a mathematical formula would be great.

Comment: Can you treat the measurements to be on a plane or do you need geodesic calculations?

Comment: I think with EPSG 32635 (UTM 35N) we are on a  plane anyway.

Comment: This plugin seems to do it, may be you have to chage your radians to degrees: https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-azimuth-distance-plugin

Comment: For reference: on a plane (projection) use Pythagoras, on a spheroid (e.g. WGS84) refer to the *Direct Problem* of [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Problem).

Answer (score 1):

If QGIS Field calculator is an option;

[image]

**INPUTS**

- `x_32635`: your input x-coordinate on EPSG:32645
- `y_32635`: your input y-coordinate on EPSG:32645
- `d_m`: your input distance in meters
- `az_rad`: your input azimuth in radians (nb. clockwise from north)

**Calculation**

*x_new* (x-coordinate of new point on UTM35N)

```
x(translate(geom_from_wkt('POINT('||"x_32635"||' '||"y_32635"||')'),
            "d_m"*sin("az_rad"), "d_m"*cos("az_rad")))
```

*y_new* (y-coordinate of new point on UTM35N)

```
y(translate(geom_from_wkt('POINT('||"x_32635"||' '||"y_32635"||')'),
            "d_m"*sin("az_rad"), "d_m"*cos("az_rad")))
```

*x_4326* (longitude of new point)

```
x(transform(translate(geom_from_wkt('POINT('||"x_32635"||' '||"y_32635"||')'), 
                       "d_m"*sin("az_rad"), "d_m"*cos("az_rad")), 
            'EPSG:32635', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

*y_4326* (latitude of new point)

```
y(transform(translate(geom_from_wkt('POINT('||"x_32635"||' '||"y_32635"||')'), 
                       "d_m"*sin("az_rad"), "d_m"*cos("az_rad")), 
            'EPSG:32635', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I found the solution to be

y1 = asin(sin(y1) * qCos(d/R) + cos(y) * sin(d/R) * cos(a));

x1 = x + atan2(sin(a) * sin(d/R) * cos(y), cos(d/R) - sin(y) * sin(y1));

where R is the radius of Earth , d is the distance OA and a is the azimuth.

Comment: This is only an approximation because the Earth is not a perfect sphere.

Comment: Besides that, the distance in that formula is supposed to be ellipsoidal, not planimetric.